# Consulta no mysql agrupada por hora

Tags: mysql, query, mariadb

Boa tarde. Estou realizando uma consulta no mysql e esta retorna os valores precisos.

Meu problema é exibir os valores que não retornam por ex:
Pedi para agrupar por hora ou por dia ele só retorna os valores que existem dados. Já os valores que não tem dados e deveriam retornar a data com o `count` 0 não retornam.

minha `query` é a seguinte:

```
select date_format(dt_cad, '%Y-%m-%d') d, date_format(dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y') d2, count(id_face) c, id_face 
from imagens 
where dt_cad between '2018-11-16' and '2018-11-19 23:59:59.999999'
and id_iot in (select id_iot from iot where id_user='1')
AND id_face not IN (select id_face from dados_face where (id_loja IN (SELECT id_loja from loja where id_user='1') and id_grupo = '4'))
AND id_face in (select id_face from imagens where dt_cad < '2018-11-16' and id_iot in (select id_iot from iot where id_user='1') AND id_face not IN (select id_face from dados_face where (id_loja IN (SELECT id_loja from loja where id_user='1') and id_grupo = '4')))
GROUP BY d
```

alguem poderia me auxiliar e me explicar como funciona para que eu traga as informações mesmo que não hajam contagem no db?

Comment: me ajuda aqui por favor

Comment: a query esta certa por ex vamos supor que eu tenha contagens nos dias 14 15 e 17 mas nao tenha no 16 ele nao traz o dia 16 sendo que eu precisava que retornasse dia 16 como 0